# Receive an error from my VBA code in Access 2010: "database" cannot find the object'|1'

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

So when I click the button it will open the save dialog with the correct file name and also open the report in preview mode but when I click save it gives me the error code.  I have seen others say that it is because the object isn't declared.  Can anyone help me?  If I get this to work it will save me over 6 hours of manually typing in file names every month!

```
Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Export_MLR
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Export_MLR()
On Error GoTo Export_MLR_Err
    Dim strReportName As String
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Market Rate Notification Final", acViewPreview
    strReportName = Format(Reports![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID, "00") & " " & Reports![Market Rate Notification Final].Product_Code & "-" & "Market Rate Notification Final" & "_" & Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen


Export_MLR_Exit:
    Exit Function

Export_MLR_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Export_MLR_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: I figured out my own mistake: here is the fix to the DoCmd.Outputto line:   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Market Rate Notification Final", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", strReportName, False, , , acExportQualityScreen      The only problem now is can I change the code to choose a diffrent destination folder everytime?

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> I figured out my own mistake: here is the fix to the DoCmd.Outputto
>   line:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Market Rate Notification Final",
 "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", strReportName, False, , , acExportQualityScreen
```

– Nick